# Why a public constructor is not accessible via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, class-visibility

I'm confused, when executing following code:

```
@Test
public void testAccessible() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Constructor<LinkedList> constructor = LinkedList.class.getConstructor();
    Assert.assertTrue(constructor.isAccessible());
}
```

the assertion fails, but LinkedList class has `public` default constructor. So why isAccessible() returns false?

Comment: You could use `getModifiers()` method to determine accessibility/modifiers, `isAccessible()` exists for different purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `getModifiers()` method to determine accessibility/modifiers, `isAccessible()` exists for different purpose.

Go through documentation for `Modifiers` class in java. [ [Link]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) It has methods necessary to determine visibility of a class member.

`isAccessible` allows reflection API to access any member at runtime.  By calling `Field.setAcessible(true)` you turn off the access checks for this particular Field instance, for reflection only. Now you can access it even if it is private, protected or package scope, even if the caller is not part of those scopes. You still can't access the field using normal code. The compiler won't allow it.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#isAccessible%28%29)...

> A value of false indicates that the reflected object should enforce Java language access checks

`isAccessible` has more to do with Java's security manager then it does with it's public visibility

[`Class#getConstructor(Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and [`Class#getConstructors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) both return only the `public` constructors

Answer (score -2):

```
Declaration
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
```

Pass your class object as parameter array like below.

```
Example :
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ClassDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 try {
    // returns the Constructor object of the public constructor
    Class cls[] = new Class[] { String.class };
    Constructor c = String.class.getConstructor(cls);
    System.out.println(c);
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
 }
```

}
}

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getconstructor.htm

Comment: 1- `LinkedList` has a default constructor 2- What's that got to do with the question ??